# UIImagePickerController and UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

Well, i have 2 view controllers the fist has three buttons each one represents an image on an array of images. When a user presses a button moves on the second view controller which has just an IBOutlet UIImageView to view the image. How can i do this programming trick using the UIImagePickerController? here are my files:

```
//  PhotoListViewController.h


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PhotoDetailViewController.h"



@interface PhotoListViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIButton *button;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *image1;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *image2;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *image3;

    IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label2;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label3;

    IBOutlet UILabel *nameMikro1;
    IBOutlet UILabel *nameMikro2;
    IBOutlet UILabel *nameMikro3;

    NSString *nameMikroProp;

    IBOutlet PhotoDetailViewController *photoDetailViewController;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) PhotoDetailViewController *photoDetailViewController;


-(IBAction)showImage:(id)sender;

@property (copy) NSString *nameMikroProp;

@end



//  PhotoListViewController.m


#import "PhotoListViewController.h"
#import "PhotoDetailViewController.h"

@implementation PhotoListViewController
@synthesize nameMikroProp;
@synthesize photoDetailViewController;



-(IBAction)showImage:(id)sender{
    photoDetailViewController = [[PhotoDetailViewController alloc]init];
    //photoDetailViewController.delegate = self;

    if([sender tag] == 4){
        //[photoDetailViewController.imageViewprop setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"zaab.png"]];
        //[self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES];

    }
    else if([sender tag] == 5){
    }
    else{
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:photoDetailViewController animated:YES];
    [photoDetailViewController release];


}




// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {


    NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"main" ofType:@"jpg"]]];
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"main2" ofType:@"jpg"]]];
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"main3" ofType:@"jpg"]]];
    NSMutableArray *nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [nameArray addObject:@"zaab's photo one"];
    [nameArray addObject:@"zaab's photo two"];
    [nameArray addObject:@"zaab's photo three"];

    nameMikro1.text  = nameMikroProp;
    nameMikro2.text = nameMikroProp;
    nameMikro3.text = nameMikroProp;

    if([@"zaab" isEqualToString:nameMikro1.text]) { 
        [image1 setImage:[imageArray objectAtIndex:0]];
        [image2 setImage:[imageArray objectAtIndex:1]];
        [image3 setImage:[imageArray objectAtIndex:2]];
        [label1 setText:[nameArray objectAtIndex:0]];
        [label2 setText:[nameArray objectAtIndex:1]];
        [label3 setText:[nameArray objectAtIndex:2]];
    }

    else if([@"evza" isEqualToString:nameMikro1.text]) {
        [image1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"evza.jpg"]];
    }

    [imageArray release];
    [nameArray release];


    [super viewDidLoad];

}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [nameMikro1 release];
    [nameMikro2 release];
    [nameMikro3 release];
    [label1 release];
    [label2 release];
    [label3 release];
    [image1 release];
    [image2 release];
    [image3 release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end


//  PhotoDetailViewController.h


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface PhotoDetailViewController : UIViewController<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>  {

    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageViewprop;
    UIImagePickerController *imgPicker;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageViewprop;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImagePickerController *imgPicker;

- (IBAction)grabImage;


@end


//  PhotoDetailViewController.m


#import "PhotoDetailViewController.h"


@implementation PhotoDetailViewController
@synthesize imageViewprop;
@synthesize imgPicker;

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo {
    imageViewprop.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"main" ofType:@"jpg"]];  
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)grabImage {
    [self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES];
}


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imgPicker.allowsImageEditing = NO;
    self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
    self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need an image picker controller to show an image? ImagePickerController is used to pick an image from the album or by using camera.

What you can do is to pass the image from the PhotoListViewController to PhotoDetailViewController.

In the PhotoDetailViewController, you can have a property of UIImage (synthesized),  so that you can set it before loading it. Then in the PhotoDetailVC use a UIImageView to show the image.
If you are looking for more advance functionality with image, look at the three20 framework at

[three20 at github](https://github.com/facebook/three20).

Comment: thanks for your answer karim but i know this way. I would also like to make it using an imagePickerController. If you know a way in doing so let me know. Thanks in advance.